# "href" links in JavaScript Android not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm new to Android/iOS applications. I made an app using PhoneGap, and I built it. Anyway, the links that are written like this are not working:

```
<a href="javascript:functionName();">click me</a>
```

What is the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<a onClick="functionName();" href="javascript:void(0)">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
<a id="anchorID">click me</a>

$("#anchorID").on("click", function() {
   // your JS code
});
```